# Failed to add attachments in mail using PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, yii, phpmailer

I am preparing to create a form page for a website that will require many fields for the user to fill out and that will be sent to a specified email. I am able to successfully send the emails but no attachments are found in the mails.

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];

if($model->validate())
{
    require("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PhpMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = true;
    $mail->Username = 'someaddress@gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = '465';
    $mail->Password = '*****';
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
    $mail->SetFrom('fromadd@gmail.com', 'name');
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['ContactForm']['subject'];
    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible';
    $mail->MsgHTML($_POST['ContactForm']['body']);
    $mail->AddAttachment($_POST['ContactForm']['filename']); /**Problem is here */
}
```

I have tried changing the $_POST to $_FILES too for adding attachments.

My view:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
         'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data') ,
     )); ?>
<?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'filename');?>
<?php  echo $form->error($model, 'filename');?>
```

Comment: try to `var_dump()` `$_FILES` and `$_POST`

Comment: If I am dumping $_FILES, it is giving undefined index error for "filename". But, I have defined them in my models too

Comment: but the data is in the $_FILES?

Comment: $_POST is not displaying anything for file upload. I guess its not getting uploaded to server but how can I do that?

Comment: if you `var_dump($_FILES)` and see more than `array(0) { }` the file is in the $_FILES

Comment: Yes I am able to see more than array(0). But not knowing why the attachment is not added

Comment: Does this helps you?: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/

Comment: Isn't "AddAttachment" already predefined for PHPMailer. Why should we write some code for uploading file again?

Comment: I have tried this :: 
if ($_FILES['filename']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) and this is giving an error as undefined index for 'filename'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using yii. SO lets do it in yii style.

First of create an object for the uploaded file

```
$attachment=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'filename');
if($attachment !== null){
$path= $attachment->tempName;
$name=$attachment->name;
}

// then do the coding for you mail and change this line

     $mail->AddAttachment($path,$name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch a file with

```
$_POST['']
```

You have to use

```
$_FILES['']
```

You should read this link, and just do it step by step

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp